# How do I find average-distance transform of a binary image?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, distance

The distance transform provides the distance of each pixel from the nearest boundary/contour/background pixel. I don't want closest distance, but I want to get some sort of average measure of the pixel's distance from the boundary/contour in all directions. Any suggestions for computing this distance transform would be appreciated. If there any existing algorithms and/or efficient C++ code available to compute such distance transform, that would be wonderful too.

Comment: Did you check OpenCV function: distanceTransform, and Matlab function: bwdist in?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a binary image of the contours, then you can calculate the number of boundary  pixels around each pixel within some windows (using e.g. the integral image, or `cv::blur`). This would give you something like what you want.

You might be able to combine that with normalizing the distance transform for average distances.

Comment: Hmm.. sounds like a reasonable idea. I'll give it a try. Yes, I do have binary image of the contours. But your solution would fail to produce proper distances for pixels that are farther than the window size from the contours.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "average measure of the pixel's distance from the boundary/contour in all directions", then I am afraid that you have to extract the contour and for each pixel inside the pattern, you have to compute the average distance with the pixels belonging to the contour.

An heuristic for a "rough" approximation, would be to compute many distance maps using sources points (they could be the pattern extremities), and for each pixel inside the pattern, then you compute the sum of all distances from the distance maps. But to have the exact measure, you would have to compute as many distance maps as pixels belonging to the contour. But if an approximation is "okay", then this will speed up the processing.